# Create a New User For Federated Account in B2C

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

I am failing to add an OpenId account to B2C using Microsoft Graph. What needs to be done to do an add operation?

---

##### B2C Setup as TestB2C

In Azure B2C the OpenID Connect (to my companies Azure AD) is setup as an Identity Provider.

[image: Azure B2C with target AD as a OpenID Connect]

*For this example, take the blurred out B2C above  to be `TestB2C.onmicorosoft.com` and the target openID is "Corporate AD"*.

---

##### Graph Call To Insert User into B2C

```json
{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "OmegaMan",
  "mailNickname": "OmegaM",
 "identities": [
    {
      "signInType": "userName",
      "issuer": "TestB2C.onmicrosoft.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "OmegaMan@Corporate.com"
    },
    {
      "signInType": "emailAddress",
      "issuer": "TestB2C.onmicrosoft.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "OmegaMan@Corporate.com"
    },
    {
      "signInType": "federated",
      "issuer": "Corporate.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "6ab...34"
    }
  ],
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false
  }  
}
```

The `issuerAssignedId` is from the settings placed in the Identity Providers section for the OpenId Connect. When I attempt to insert said user, I get this current error:

```json
   ...
   "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "A password must be specified to create a new user.",
    ...
```

Which for a federated user does not make sense. Note, that in a different add operation for an "email user", this process works; with different settings.  What is missing to then add a federated user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to circumvent the user "Sign-Up" after user insertion. The issue turned out to be, that to have proper federation occur, the proper values need to be in place.

```
 "identities": [     
    {
      "signInType": "federated",
      "issuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX/v2.0",
      "issuerAssignedId": "YYYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYY"
```

What was happening was that I was using `"issuer": "myDomain.com"` which was not resolving correctly to do a login; to which the user then had to "SignUp" via the federated IP and ended up with two logins.

By changing issuer from a DNS readable name, to the Microsoft login url with my AD directories' ID (the number provided when switching domain in Azure, XXXX-XXX ... btw) and also a proper `issuerAssignedId`, found from the originating AD issuer, it worked and the user was added.

Answer (score 1):

For a federated user, "accountEnabled" is false.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to the *why* of your answer?